# Should question titles be more general or more specific?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, meta

Should question titles be worded to describe the broader ideas of the question, or should they be made as specific as possible? For example, I recently made a [post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/90823/can-a-bike-fit-compensate-for-10-30mm-deviations-in-reach-and-stack-from-a-known) asking how to make Trek FX Sport 4 fit more like a Specialized Sirrus 4. I worded the title to about the general idea of changing one bike to fit similar to another bike. I thought this wording would help people in similar situations (but with different specific bikes) find my post. On the other hand, I could have made a more specific title about the specific bikes in question, such "Can I make a FX Sport 4 fit like a Sirrus 4?" Is a more general or more specific title better, and in what ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generalised question is going to apply to more situations, but there's also a risk of being "too general"

Aiming for the happy medium, and using the specific bikes as examples might work best, else we could have a lot of distinct questions about permutations of specific models.

---

Your question is well documented and has some good answers.

The differences between the two bikes are relatively small, mostly under 10mm but exactly how those translate into quantifiable differences?   That is, if there's more rake but less trail, does that translate to no-overall change or does one outweigh the other?   Increased trail and rake mean the bike wants to go straight-ahead easier, and requires more effort to turn.   Decreases in either would result in a "twitchier" handling bike that turns faster, but needs active help to stay straight.   How they combine is unlikely to be linear.

Ultimately, as with a lot of things in cycling they can't be calculated, and the best answer is to get on and go for a test-ride.  Yes that's somewhat of a cop-out but what matters is how it feels to the rider.